# How can offline videos be played only within your app and not be accessed from anywhere else

Tags: java, android

If you look at learning apps like pluralsight app or apps like youtube, they offer the option of downloading an app for offline watching. but you are not able to accesses those downloaded videos from anywhere else aside from within the app. thus cant be transfered. I would like to implement a functionality like that for copyright reasons.

Comment: Store them in `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()` (methods available on `Context`). Those are read-write for your app and are not accessible by any other app, except on rooted devices.

Comment: Use drm protected contents

Comment: You could crypt them and store them anywhere - other things aren't possible